To what temperature does a regular AC lower the temperature
In a regular working AC in a household, in order to cool a room, the AC has to have a working fluid at a lower temperature than the room temperature.
Say if the room temperature is $\vartheta_R = 22^{\circ}C$ how lower than that is the temperature of the working fluid before it enters the evaporator?
Additional question:
I have the option to choose the temperature to what I want my room to be cooled to. If I decrease and I put $\vartheta_R = 16^{\circ}C$ does the AC lower the temperature (expand the working fluid to lower pressures) of the working fluid or does it always stay the same?

It not only depends on the room temperature, but also the outside environment.  If the outside environment is too hot then there is potential for your AC unit to actually warm the room.  You AC unit should give operational temperature ranges.

based on observational experience and seeing frost and ice form on the interior grill / heat exchanger of a sleeve (through wall) AC Unit, I would say the temperature is below freezing.

why would the temperature of the working fluid have to be lower than the room temperature?

@jsotola so heat can be absorbed in the evaporator - usually by a fluid absorbing heat energy to become a gas. The latent heat of vaporisation.

@SolarMike the OP asked about temperature of the working fluid before it enters the evaporator ... that fluid can be at higher than room temperature because of the large temperature drop when it evaporates

@jstola The temperature drop occurs before the evaporator. During the evaporation the temperature of the working fluid remains constant. Phase change is an isothermal process.

I’ll talk about a basic domestic split system, where the condensing unit is outside and the evaporator coil is inside in the air handler unit.
The compressor compresses the refrigerant vapor to a high pressure and temperature. In the condensing coil this is cooled to a little above ambient (It has to be higher than ambient for heat transfer). The hot liquid is fed to the evaporator coil, through an expansion valve, or other device to ensure that the pressure in the evaporator coil is low. As the hot liquid enters this low pressure region a fraction of the liquid (about 15%) will flash off instantly to vapor to cool the rest of the liquid. So, before the refrigerant enters the coil it is below room temperature.
Inside the evaporator coil (and the condenser coil) there is a mixture of liquid and vapor. For any particular refrigerant (except for blends) there is a direct relationship between pressure and temperature, as can be read from a PT chart. This means that for any pressure in the coil the refrigerant mix will have a set temperature.
Generally the air leaving the coil should be 6 to 12 centigrade degrees colder than the air it is cooling, this means that the temperature of the coil should be 9 to 15 centigrade degrees lower than room temperature to allow for heat transfer from the cooled air.
Most air conditioning systems have a design temperature of $35^oC$ ambient, (That is 1% of the time the ambient temperature is higher than this). When ambient temperature is higher than this they will not work at their maximum capacity.
For your second question, as the air in the room cools the temperature and pressure in the evaporator coil decreases.  So when the room temp gets down to $16^oC$ the temperature in the coil will be about $1^oC$-$7^oC$ and you may have your coil icing up.

So the evaporation of the liquid part of the working fluid in the expansion valve takes up the heat (via. latent heat) from the working fluid and thus decreases the total temperature of the whole mixture? And the part with "adiabatic expansion of gasses" that decrease the temperature is not actually the main cause of temperature decrease?

There is no adiabatic expansion of gases here. The Gas Laws do not apply to saturated vapor. As long as there is saturated vapor in contact with liquid, if you hold either the temperature or pressure constant the other will also be constant no matter how much the volume increases. The latent heat of evaporation is the only mechanism for cooling, not the expansion of "gas". The gas laws only apply at conditions far away from where a vapor is saturated. Through the coil the liquid gradually evaporates which causes cooling. Only at the very end of the coil, when there is no liquid left (next-)

does the vapor expand and take in heat. This is the zone known as "super-heated vapor". It is important -you don't want any liquid refrigerant slugging back to the compressor. As you know liquid is almost incompressible and will damage the pistons or valves.


Here’s a way to examine the whole refrigeration cycle:
1 Low temperature, low pressure saturated vapor.
2 High temperature, high pressure super-heated vapor.
3 High temperature, high pressure saturated liquid.
4 Low temperature, low pressure saturated vapor/liquid mix.
1-2 Compressor compresses low pressure vapor to high pressure. It maintains low pressure in the evaporator and high pressure in the condenser. Note the line slopes slightly to the left as enthalpy is increases due to heat of compression.
2-3 Condenser ejects excess heat to ambient. Line is horizontal, temperature and pressure are constant as enthalpy decreases.
3-4 Metering device (TEV valve, cap tube etc.) maintains the pressure difference between the high side and low side whilst metering sufficient refrigerant to maintain evaporator temperature and pressure. Note line is vertical - no enthalpy change in refrigerant. Sensible heat of condensed liquid becomes latent heat of refrigerant vapor at low temperature and pressure. Here approximately 25% of refrigerant has to be flashed off to accomplish this. This flashed vapor has no possibility to be used for cooling load.
4-1 Evaporator exchanges heat with load. Note line is horizontal; temperature and pressure remain constant as enthalpy increase with heat from load.

In residential AC.s the exit flow from the coils is around sixty Fahrenheit. The AC technicians check them with a thermometer after servicing or adding refrigerant.
The recommended thermostat setting is 78 Fahrenheit, but for the elderly, it could be set to 75.
Commercial spaces and shopping malls have different zones the goal of which is to provide more comfort in public areas and save on storage or utility areas.

Who are these old people who want it colder?  My experience with the elderly is they want it 82.

Many of the old folks live in old houses with no insulation. So they set the thermostat lower. Like some of my old neighborhood in San Fernando Valley! They waste a lot of energy.
